# How to show that for any initial probability this Markov chain has the same distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

I'm currently trying to solve this problem about Markov chains.

> Let a Markov chain have the transition probability matrix:
>
> $$
> P =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 - \alpha & \alpha \\
> \beta & 1 - \beta
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> where $|1 - \alpha - \beta| \lt 1$.
>
> 1) Find the $n$-step transition matrix $P^n$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
>
> 2) Show that for any initial probability the Markov chain has the same probability distribution as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

For the first problem, I was able to find that the transition matrix is:

$$
P^n = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\alpha + \beta(1 - \alpha - \beta)^n}{\alpha + \beta} & \dfrac{\alpha - \alpha(1 - \alpha - \beta)^n}{\alpha + \beta} \\
\dfrac{\beta - \beta(1 - \alpha - \beta)^n}{\alpha + \beta} & \dfrac{\beta + \alpha(1 - \alpha - \beta)^n}{\alpha + \beta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and so for $n \rightarrow \infty$ we have:

$$
P^{n \rightarrow \infty} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} & \dfrac{\alpha}{\alpha + \beta} \\
\dfrac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta} & \dfrac{\beta}{\alpha + \beta}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

If I'm incorrect, please let me know.

What's confusing me is the second problem. To be completely frank, I don't recall learning this in the course I'm taking and I'm having trouble finding resources online, which led me to ask a question here. How would I solve this problem? I'm having trouble from where to begin.

Any tips or feedback are appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Let $\pi$ be the initial distribution, let $Q$ be your limit matrix.  You have to show that $\pi Q$ does not depend on $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $Q = \lim_{n\to\infty} P^n$. For any initial distribution $\alpha=(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$, we have
$$
\alpha Q=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_0&\alpha_1\end{pmatrix}\left(
\large\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\alpha }{\alpha +\beta } & \frac{\alpha }{\alpha +\beta } \\
 \frac{\beta }{\alpha +\beta } & \frac{\beta }{\alpha +\beta } \\
\end{array}
\right)
= \left(
\Large\begin{array}{cc}
 \frac{\alpha  \alpha _0}{\alpha +\beta }+\frac{\beta  \alpha _1}{\alpha +\beta } & \frac{\alpha  \alpha _0}{\alpha +\beta }+\frac{\beta  \alpha _1}{\alpha +\beta } \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which shows that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb P(X_n=j\mid X_0=i)$ is independent of $i$.